# Google Drive SDK: Is it possible to list and access files that are shared to the entire domain/organization?

Tags: google-drive-api

Specifically, when User A has set file Foo to be shared as "People at Domain can find and access", but has NOT explicitly placed User B under "Add People:". Is it possible to programmatically list and view file Foo as User B (where User A and B are under the same Domain)?

*Note, it is possible for User B to manually search for and view "Foo" by using Google Drive's advanced search feature. But I have not been able to do this programmatically via drive.files.list or drive.children.list. It seems that "Foo" only gets returned from these lists if 1) User B has accessed the file or 2) User A has explicitly included User B under "Add people". Is there a way to programmatically list and access files like "Foo" when neither of these two conditions are not met?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, searching with the Drive SDK searches only files a user has or has been explicitly shared with them.

I believe this could be better, so I will investigate. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks Ali for the answer and amazing response time. Excited to see these APIs get more and more powerful.